# Is there a way within Azure DevOps to Change the (Parent/Root) "Area Path" without needing to change the Project Name?

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

Is there a way within Azure DevOps to Change the (Parent/Root) "Area Path" without needing to change the Project Name? We've already invested time in configuration across our ADO Project, and the team does not want to go through the configuration needed for a Project Name change.  They prefer to go the least risky path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way within Azure DevOps to Change the (Parent/Root) "Area Path" without needing to change the Project Name?

I am afraid that there is **no** such method to directly change the Parent/Root Area Path name.

Root classification nodes can't be modified after being created unless you modify the name of the project.

**Workaround:**

You can create secondary nodes to classify area path. Then you could change the area path name via `Edit` option.

[image]

You can also continue to create child nodes on the basis of secondary nodes.

On the other hand, you  could also submit a suggestion about this feature on [Our UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

[image]